# How to have a configurable @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation

Tags: java, maven, annotations, jax-ws, wildfly-8

I am having a maven build and project with a webservice client that will be deployed on a wildfly server.
In my Client EJB, I have the following

```
@Stateless
public class MyClientEJB {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorldService?wsdl")
    private HelloWorldService service;
```

I want to have different url for Test and Production, how can I have this url as a configurable entry. I tried creating profiles in my pom.xml file but that requires following code and I don't know how to use it in @WebServiceRef annotation.

```
private void initProperties() {
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties");

    if (is != null) {
        try {
            properties.load(is);

            BASE_URL = (String)properties.getProperty("student.restws.url");    

        } catch (IOException e) {               
            logger.error("Error when reading properties: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not load application.properties file.");
        }
    } else {        
        logger.error("Error when finding application.properties.");
        throw new RuntimeException("Error when finding application.properties.");
    }
}
```

Any example would be appreciated. Thanks

Update:

I added wsdl folder under src/main/resources/META_INF and copied the wsdl file there.
In the @WebServiceRef annotation then updated to
    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl")

But I get the following runtime error when webservice is invoked.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JBAS015526: Child 'META-INF/wsdl/HelloWorld.wsdl' not found for VirtualFile: "/C:/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/bin/content/hello-world.war"
```

wsdl file has the following defined:

```
<wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
  <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldEndpointBinding" >
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:9090/HelloWorldPort"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Did you add it to `META-INF` or `META-INF/wsdl`? Keep in mind that the file must be accessible from the classpath.

Comment: Try with leading /. I guess `META_INF` is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have dynamic strings in annotations.

But you could use `@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "META-INF/wsdl/service.wsdl")` and use maven profiles to copy the right file to this location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see my update above, I am still having issues

Comment: Of course you can have dynamic text in annotations. That's the whole point of EL

Comment: @kolossus EL is dynamic, the value you put on the annotation is static.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://victor-ichim.blogspot.com/2012/02/dynamic-wsdl-location-with-jax-ws.html the correct approach is to:

> Fix the wsdl location by saving the contract locally.
>
> 1. Generate the JAX-WS artifacts and save the wsdl
> 2. Point the service reference to the local wsdl
> 3. Include the wsdl in the deployment unit

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem. Put `beans.xml` to `webapp/WEB-INF`

`beans.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee";
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">;
</beans>
```

Comment: Please re-edit your answer instead of putting a part of the answer in a comment. Answers are easier to format as well.